# Can someone explain the scene where Tony Stark first meets Brandt?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3

Ok, in Iron Man 3 we see Tony on his way to the bar to meet with the soldier’s mom. However, I could have sworn he bumps into Brandt (scarred Extremis fake Homeland Security agent) coming **OUT** of the bar.

This confused me because if she was already in the bar, then why didn’t she get the file?

Why did she leave and then come back?

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, *someone* can explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She appeared to be checking out the environment dressed as a waitress. I had the impression she was making sure she knew who was in the bar when she returns. Passing Stark on the way out was just a cherry on top. When she leaves, it is to go and put on her official government-looking clothing. When she comes back to the bar, she is wearing a completely different outfit.

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't notice that; it still seems strange that she would do that first; caution and subtlety didn't seem to be the Extremis way...

Comment: I suspect they used some degree of subtlety when they could. Otherwise they would have show up at some point during their ten years AIM was developing their technology. I think they did an admirable job of remaining hidden considering how pronounced a mistake could be. I think their agents only used extreme force when necessary. Note Brandt's attempt to bluff the local sheriff when she was trying to nab Stark.

Answer (score 1):

Brandt was not coming out of the bar when she bumped into Tony Stark.  As Tony was making his way into the bar she bumped into him as she walked past the bar on the sidewalk.

Comment: Ahh, no I'm sorry; she was clearly dressed as a waitress coming out of the bar as Thaddeus described.

Answer (score 0):

After rewatching the movie yesterday, I'm positive that [@Kevin Robinson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35792/can-someone-explain-the-scene-where-tony-stark-first-meets-brandt#67028) is right.

Brandt wasn't shown coming out of the bar. As as far as we can see, she is walking past the bar. It's unclear where she's coming from or where she's going to.

Later, in the bar, she's dressed absolutely the same, except the coat:

Outside:

[image: Ellen Brandt outside of the bar, in the coat]

In the bar:

[image: Ellen Brandt inside the bar, without the coat, in the same shirt]